# BigDecimal addition gives 0 in a function

Tags: java

I have the following Junit

```
private void calculatePF(BigDecimal leftPF,
        BigDecimal rightPF) {
    rightPF = rightPF.add(new BigDecimal(10));
    leftPF = leftPF.add(new BigDecimal(10));
}

@Test
public void autoPlaceUser() throws Exception{
    BigDecimal leftPF = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal rightPF = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    calculatePF(leftPF, rightPF);
    System.out.println("rightPF : "+rightPF);
    System.out.println("leftPF : "+leftPF);

}
```

I still don't understand why the values are still zero even though I have perform addition and assign it to the variables. Anything I miss here ?

Comment: `BigDecimal`s are immutable, so you need to change your method to _return_ the calculated value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BigDecimal` is *immutable*. The values that you assign to `leftPF` and `rightPF` are not going to change, until you re-assign these variables.

If you would like to get an observable side effect from your `calculatePF`, pass your `BigDecimal`s to it in an array, like this:

```
private void calculatePF(BigDecimal[] pf) {
    pf[1] = pf[1].add(new BigDecimal(10));
    pf[0] = pf[0].add(new BigDecimal(10));
}
@Test
public void autoPlaceUser() throws Exception{
    BigDecimal pf[] = new BigDecimal[] {
        BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ZERO
    };
    calculatePF(pf);
    System.out.println("rightPF : "+pf[1]);
    System.out.println("leftPF : "+pf[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things happening here:

- `BigDecimal` is immutable. When you perform an operation on it, it returns a *new* `BigDecimal` instance.
- Java is **pass by value**. `leftPF` and `rightPF` inside `calculatePF` are *copies* of the original references.
- You cannot *reseat* references in Java. When you reassign `rightPF` by doing `rightPF = rightPF.add(new BigDecimal(10));`, you're changing the value of the *local* `rightPF` and not the one in `autoPlaceUser`; that one still points to the original `rightPF`. The same applies to `leftPF`.

So what do you do here? You have to assign the *new* instances to the *original* `rightPF` and `leftPF`. There are many ways you can do this:

- Create a separate method for `rightPF` and `leftPF` and then do `rightPF = calcRightPF(rightPF)`.
- Simply doing it inline; it's not a lot of code, so could just do it online.
- Encapsulate `rightPF` and `leftPF` inside another object. Then you don't even have to return it; you can just set `rightPF` and `leftPF` on that object itself inside your method (using setters).
- Use an array (`BigDecimal[]`) for `leftPF` an `rightPF` and assign the new instances to the appropriate subscripts. You won't have to return the array here since you are directly modifying it (see dasblinkenlight's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30539053/263004)). This is similar to encapsulating it inside an object, but you're just using an array here instead.

Answer (score 1):

Java is **pass-by-value**: when the `BigDecimal` variable `rightPF` is re-assigned in the method that adds the numbers, the original variable passed by the caller method remains the same.

To resolve this, you need to return the new values. One way is to have the method return an array of `BigDecimal`s containing the new values:

```
private BigDecimal[] calculatePF(BigDecimal leftPF,
        BigDecimal rightPF) {
    rightPF = rightPF.add(new BigDecimal(10));
    leftPF = leftPF.add(new BigDecimal(10));
    return new BigDecimal[] {leftPF, rightPF};
}

public void autoPlaceUser() throws Exception{
    BigDecimal leftPF = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal rightPF = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal[] newPF = calculatePF(leftPF, rightPF);
    System.out.println("rightPF : " + newPF[1]);
    System.out.println("leftPF : " + newPF[0]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the new values just to the variables in the function calculatePF. The actual values being printed never get changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a scoping issue.

The leftPf and rightPf variables in your calculatePf() method are scoped to be inside that method.

The leftPf and rightPf variables in your autoPlaceUser() method are scoped to be inside that method.

They are 2 completely different sets of variables.